# Moodle does not load label modules from datebase

Tags: php, moodle

Moodle-Version 2.3

I inserted into the tabels: course_modules and label

The insertion works well, but the data which is put into the labels table isn't displayed.

The label asdasdasda (with id 207) is created by the moodle-frontend and the asdasdasd (with id 206) is created by me.

207 is displayed.

206 is not displayed.

LABEL: id, course, name, intro, introformat, time
[image: LABEL: id, course, name, intro, introformat, time]

MODULES: id, name, version, cron, lastcron, search, visible
[image: MODULES: id, name, version, cron, lastcron, search, visible]

COURSE_MOULES:
id, course, module, instance, section, idnumber, added, score, indent, visible, visibleold, groupmode, groupingid, groupmembersonly, completion, completiongradeitemnumber, completionview, completionexpected, availablefrom, availableuntil, showavailability, showdescription
[image: COURSE_MOULES]

Additionalinfos:

If I use a displayed label und edit its content in the database, the new content isn't displayed.
The changed content doesn't appear with a renewed Browser-cache oder with a purged Moodle-cache, but it appears in the edit-form.

If I agree with the form an press 'Save and return to course' without editing the content in the form the content (which was edit on the database) appears in the course.

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you trying to do?

If you are creating a new module - then the correct way is to create code in /mod/yourmodname

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Activity_modules

If you just want to change the labels, then use the language editor

http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Language_customization

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to insert values to the course modules from back end.

All entries in the course_module table will not be shown in the course modules list. The course modules should be present in the course_sections tables and modinfo field in the course table.